# Custom Validation in Ektron Smartfrom Definition

Tags: xslt, ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.7.

I am trying to add a custom validation logic to my smartform definition.
I have a check box and text box fields in my smartform definition,i need to make the text box read only if the check box checked property is true.
The custom validation options available in the smartform editor fields doesn't have any such option.

How can i achieve this? 
I have gone through custom validation knowledge base article in ektron(http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=7420).

But i couldn't get the property of smartform element
in order to define the logic.Is this possible through XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a text box read only if a check box is checked doesn't really fall into 'validation' -- sounds like you want to use the relevance feature, which allows you to hide or show form fields based on values of other fields. For example, you could show a read only version of the field when the check box is checked, and an editable version when it is unchecked. You can additionally apply validation logic on the text box that's displayed. Here are some related resources to help you get going with this http://bit.ly/cXiaKd -- http://bit.ly/11gedde